# How to manage event for made a load bars in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, load

I created an application with Access (2013) with VBA. This application crawls a website and inserts some records into database. But it takes too much time.

My solution is to make load bars for waiting. But currently I use the event `Form_Current()`; and when I set the load bar's value (it's my function) `setBarLoadValue (25)` Nothing is displayed on the screen. Why ? Because my function run yet.

My question is: **How I can manage the event to simulate a load bar in real time ?** (Don't want to wait till the end of function to see 100%).

Comment: Does your function include DoEvents?  That allows the screen to refresh, thus displaying your progress bar's...progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an solution !

## Solution

### Step1

You must enter this code in your code

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, Me.Name
Me.Repaint
DoEvents
```

With this code, you display immediately the form

### Step 2

Now, when you want to display something, you must just do that: `DoEvents`.

When you use `DoEvents` the form refresh and you can display the new state of the progress bar.

---

**Note**: This solution work with Access 2013. Maybe it's not supported with other version.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has a beautifully designed Progress status bar. http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=265537

The author of the code has provided a Class where you have a Form that acts as a Meter and you basically set the values. It could be real time enough, have a look. I use it in my application and works great.